# Dealing with internationalization and form submission errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, internationalization

In rails if you have a resource (example books) the url to create it as at

```
/books/new
```

If there's an error when you try to create a new book (resource) the url becomes

```
/books
```

This is causing problems for me with internationalization. If a user has errors while creating a new book they will see some error message and they'll be put on the url `/books`. If my user is for some reason on the "wrong" language, then when they try to change the language they'll see a different page since instead of `/books/new` they're on `/books`. Not only that, but the error message will no longer be there after they change languages.

How do you guys handle these situations? Should I just not let users change languages when they are submitting a new book? I'm sure there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your create action, you can get the language in all the time by fixing your locale I18n.locale even if it's in your book params, like :

```
I18n.locale = params[:book][:locale]
```

If you fix the locale in your create action you can be sure the user see the good locale.